# How to compile C++11 RNG sample using MinGW 4.5.2 and boost

Tags: c++, boost, random

I never used boost before. I downloaded MinGW bundle which comes with many other libraries and among them is boost.I have older version of g++ and want to use boost to compile code from this site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random
to avoid using something like: `std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );`
I want to start actively using C++11 features but first I'd like to achieve this just by using boost in this case(I will download 4.6.x later)
The code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    // Seed with a real random value, if available
    std::random_device rd;

    // Choose a random mean between 1 and 6
    std::default_random_engine e1(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);
    int mean = uniform_dist(e1);
    std::cout << "Randomly-chosen mean: " << mean << '\n';

    // Generate a normal distribution around that mean
    std::mt19937 e2(rd());
    std::normal_distribution<> normal_dist(mean, 2);

    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[std::round(normal_dist(e2))];
    }
    std::cout << "Normal distribution around " << mean << ":\n";
    for (auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

ideone compiles it. But using  g++ main.cpp -std=c++0x -I c:\MinGW\include\boost\
 I get error:

```
PS C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\C++\snippets> g++ randomBoost.cpp -std=c++0x -I c:\MinGW\include\boost\
randomBoost.cpp: In function 'int main()':
randomBoost.cpp:29:17: error: expected initializer before ':' token
randomBoost.cpp:33:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
randomBoost.cpp:33:1: error: expected ';' before '}' token
randomBoost.cpp:33:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
randomBoost.cpp:33:1: error: expected ')' before '}' token
randomBoost.cpp:33:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
randomBoost.cpp:33:1: error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

Thank you.

Comment: I got many errors just using g++ main.cpp

Comment: what boost utilities do you want to use?

Comment: the ones which are needed to compile this code ?

Comment: None of those look like boost libraries.  Boost libraries usually have boost in their name or path.

Comment: They probably arent, the page suppose you have c++11 compatible compiler

Comment: The headers (and therefore the RNGs) you are using are from C++11's standard library. What's your problem with this code ?